# Calling a React function PropType from outside the class definition

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have the following React Component..

```
import React, { Component,PropTypes } from 'react';
import RequestListItem from '../RequestListItem';
import { ScrollView,Text,View } from 'react-native';

class  RequestList extends Component {


  render(){
    return (
      <ScrollView
        onScroll={() => { console.log('onScroll!'); }}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        scrollEventThrottle={200}>
        {this.props.requests.map(mapRequests)}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

RequestList.propTypes = {
  requests: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  onRequestItemClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

var mapRequests = (request, i) => {
  <RequestListItem
      id={request.id}
      title={request.title}
      onRequestItemClick={this.props.onRequestItemClick.bind(this)}
  />
};

export default RequestList;
```

The problem I am having is concerning the `mapRequest` function. I need to be able to invoke the `onRequestItemClick` that is passed in as a property to this component,but since this is defined outside of the class definition, it doesn't appear I have access to the properties. How do I accomplish what the code above is trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the callback to the `mapRequests` method, instead of trying to pull it directly from the props:

```
class RequestList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.props.onRequestItemClick = this.props.onRequestItemClick.bind(this) // I'm not sure why your binding to this something you got from the props, so consider removing this line
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <ScrollView
        onScroll={() => { console.log('onScroll!'); }}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        scrollEventThrottle={200}>
        {this.props.requests.map((request) => mapRequests(request, this.props.onRequestItemClick))} // the arrow function calls mapRequest, and passes the request and the callback 
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

var mapRequests = (request, onRequestItemClick) => {
  <RequestListItem
      id={request.id}
      title={request.title}
      onRequestItemClick={onRequestItemClick}
  />
};
```

However, if you already use an anonymous function, you don't need `mapRequests` function anyway:

```
class RequestList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.props.onRequestItemClick = this.props.onRequestItemClick.bind(this) // I'm not sure why your binding to this something you got from the props, so consider removing this line
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <ScrollView
        onScroll={() => { console.log('onScroll!'); }}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        scrollEventThrottle={200}>
        {this.props.requests.map((request) => (
            <RequestListItem
                id={request.id}
                title={request.title}
                onRequestItemClick={this.props.onRequestItemClick}        
            />
        )}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I originally tried this and was having issues, but I went back and tried it again and it worked!